# Use jQuery to Remove a DIV if there is an Undefined Inline Background Image

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement to move an image from a CMS post to an inline css  background-image so that it can be displayed as a parallax image.  I have managed to get this far;

```
<div class="parallax-wrap">
  <div id="background-1">
   <section class="background-1 home-parallax"></section>
   <div class="row description">
    <div class="column small-12">
       <h2 class="text-center" style="margin:2em 0;">{{  title }} </h2>
       <div class="clear:both;"></div>
       <p><img src="https://cdn.ecommercedns.uk/...image.jpg" />Some description text here.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
     if($(this).next().find('img').attr('src')!= "") {
      $('.background-1').css('background-image', function() {
        return 'url(' + $(this).next().find('img').attr('src') + ')'
      });
      $('.description img').remove();

     }
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

This on the output WHEN an image is defined;

```
<div class="parallax-wrap">
  <div id="background-1">
   <section class="background-1 home-parallax" style="background-image: url("https://cdn.ecommercedns.uk/...image.jpg");"></section>
   <div class="row description">
    <div class="column small-12">
       <h2 class="text-center" style="margin:2em 0;">Page Title</h2>
       <div class="clear:both;"></div>
       <p></p><p></p><p>Description Text</p><p></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
     if($(this).next().find('img').attr('src')!= "") {
      $('.background-1').css('background-image', function() {
        return 'url(' + $(this).next().find('img').attr('src') + ')'
      });
      $('.description img').remove();
     }
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

It works, but I need to account for there being no image to move.  Currently it leaves the inline image background with this **style="background-image: url("undefined");"** if no image exists.

```
<div class="parallax-wrap">
  <div id="background-1">
   <section class="background-1 home-parallax" style="background-image: url(&quot;undefined&quot;);"></section>
   <div class="row description">
    <div class="column small-12">
       <h2 class="text-center" style="margin:2em 0;">Page Title</h2>
       <div class="clear:both;"></div>
       <p></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
     if($(this).next().find('img').attr('src')!= "") {
      $('.background-1').css('background-image', function() {
        return 'url(' + $(this).next().find('img').attr('src') + ')'
      });
      $('.description img').remove();
     }
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

I think the best approach would be to avoid this happening in the first place and create the entire section tag IF the image does exist.

I need to remove that -or- create the section, with the jQuery rather than adding the inline style to the existing key in the first place.

Comment: `if($(this).next().find('img').attr('src')!= "")`,  from where you reading this img tag,

Comment: The CMS post {{ Description }}

Comment: Sorry, what exactly you looking for, are you looking for better code or you facing any issue in the current code.

Comment: I updated the question, maybe this is better?

Comment: `$('section.background-1).filter(function() { return $(this).css('background-image') == 'url("undefined")' });` . But probably better to intercept it at the point where it was inserted.

Comment: So a secondary check on the src?  I'm not sure how to do that.  I'm not a jQuery kind of guy.

Answer (score 0):

by getting `attr('src')` you can get its full value only via HTML tag src, for example, if you have an image with `<img src='test.png'>` and you would do.

`$('img').attr('src');` it would return `test.png`.
However if you are adding it via css (Background image), you have to
`$('img').css('background-image');` in your case it would return `'url(undefined)';`

So I would think this is supposed to work out for you.

```
$(window).load(function() {
 if($(this).next().find('img').css('background-image') != 'url("undefined")') {
  $('.background-1').css('background-image', function() {
    return 'url(' + $(this).next().find('img').attr('src') + ')'
  });
  $('.description img').remove();
 }
});
```

I would recommend doing it the proper way, and checking it trough jquery itself, however like you said, you aren't friendly with jQuery, I guess it should do the job.

Comment: Regrettably it is doing the same thing. I think I am going to have to establish if the image exists or not first.

Comment: You know you could allways debug it down. `console.log($(this).next().find('img').css('background-image'));`, see what it returns, and etc. See what output returns `attr('src')`, and you could allways add some custom elements if you have the image production tab, for example you can use custom objects as `.data({OnOff: 'on'});` or simular, there is usually way to get it done.

Comment: Thank you, that is extremely helpful.  Not so easy when you don't know the question!

Comment: @Stuart No problem, by the way, since it css whos responsible, I think it might not be finding file and actually setting undefined of image. I would just add class and check if has class `$(this).addClass('noneed);` and then check with `$(this).hasClass('noneed);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parallax-wrap">
  <div id="background-1">
   <section class="background-1 home-parallax">
    <div class="caption">
     <span class="border">{{ title }}</span>
    </div>
   </section>
   <div class="row description">
    <div class="column small-12">{{ description|raw }}</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('.description div').each(function(){
     if($(this).find('img').length){

         $('.background-1').css('background-image', function(){
          return 'url(' + $(this).next().find('img').attr('src') + ')'
         });
         $('.description img').remove();
     } else {

         $('.parallax-wrap').remove();

     }
    });
  </script>
</div>
```